# Is it possible to overide the sort function in the jQuery tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm currently using tablesorter to sort a set of graphs. I achieve this by using a hidden  text to embed the "number" the graph contents represent. The textExtraction routine then pulls the number out for sorting.

However the graphs are actually for two separate things, lets call them A & B where a B node is a child of one of the A nodes. So what I really want is to sort unrelated B nodes with respect to their parents number unless they are being sorted to a sibling B node. This would maintain the relationship between the parent nodes and the siblings amongst themselves. For example:

```
A1 (100)
B2  (25)
B3  (10)
A2 (50)
B1 (25)
B4 (5)

Where B2&B3 are parents of A1 and B1 & B4 are parents of A2
```

Is there anyway I can override the sort method to do this complex thing?

Comment: In the end I tweaked the hidden values I sort by to achieve the same effect. So each "A" became 2*Value and each related B became 1*Parent A+Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the answer is no.